# leaving gap from top in panel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

[image]

I have taken this snapshot from netbeans.what is the method to add vertical gap from jpanel ? (i.e vertical gap from panel to the first component )

Comment: open the generated code and see for yourself, it's the best way to know what NetBeans do.

Comment: What LayoutManager is used in jPanel? Could you post some code?

Comment: @ MByD it very tough to read in from there.Netbeans has used group layout

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways. Either you let the layout manager take care of it, or you could use a `BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder`.

Comment: @ aioobe Unable to get that effect using `BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder` I used `mypanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(50,50,50,50));` but that vertical does not change.