# Unable to leave vertical gap

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.URI;

class MainPageTypo {
    JFrame fr;
    JButton easy, medium, tough;
    JLabel Contact;

    MainPageTypo() {
        buildGUI();
        hookUpEvents();
    }

    public void buildGUI() {
        fr = new JFrame("TypoMaster");
        JPanel mainP = new JPanel();
        mainP.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel LevelPanel = new JPanel();
        LevelPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 0, 50, 50));
        easy = new JButton("Easy");
        medium = new JButton("Medium");
        tough = new JButton("Tough");
        Contact = new JLabel("Visit my Blog");
        fr.add(mainP);
        LevelPanel.add(easy);
        LevelPanel.add(medium);
        LevelPanel.add(tough);
        LevelPanel.setBackground(Color.magenta);
        LevelPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(50, 50, 50, 50));
        mainP.add(LevelPanel);
        mainP.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        fr.setSize(500, 500);
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setVisible(true);
        // fr.setResizable(false);
    }

    public void hookUpEvents() {

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new MainPageTypo();
    }
}
```

This is my complete code.I want to leave vertical space from top of JPanel().I am using  `LevelPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(50,50,50,50));`
 but unable to get vertical gap.How can i get this?

Comment: duplcate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879992/leaving-gap-from-top-in-panel - nothing new compared to that, as far as I can see.

Comment: @kleopatra same question as before, but there is something new indeed: now there is code! That makes a big difference no?

Comment: @jfpoilpret - missed the obvious :-)

Comment: But I agree that the OP should have edited his first question instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what you are saying I am only guessing that you might be after something you get by setting the border on the main panel:

```
mainP.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(50, 50, 50, 50));
```

Please give us more details. Because you are getting the gap. Maybe draw a quick and nasty picture. :)

**Recommendation**
Please follow Java naming conventions, i.e. variables names should start from lowercase letter.

Comment: @ Boro
yes that is what i wanted,but why is `LevelPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(50, 50, 50, 50));` not producing results

Comment: @Meprogrammer,  It does produce results.  Just not the same ones you are looking for when you set the border on the mainP.  Compare them both side by side and you will see the buttons are the same height in the frame.  The difference is where the space is placed.

Comment: @  jzd when i write `LevelPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(50, 50, 50, 50))` why does not LevelPanel shift downwards?

Comment: @Meprogrammer It doesn't move down since you are setting the border for it, and the border is part of a component, thus it increases its size (width & height accordingly). In case where you set the border for `mainP` the space of 'the gap' is taken by the border while size of the `levelPanel` stays unchanged, thus you have the wanted effect.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you have to understand which part of the puzzle is responsible for what

- setting a Border on a container (here levelPanel) *adds* space-requirement to the container itself (as @Boro already explained): the LayoutManager apply to that container will layout the children of the container only inside the insets as requested by the border. That's what you are seeing in levelPanel, the red above the first button, below the last button (and to the sides of all buttons)
- setting x/y gap properties in a LayoutManager which support this, has effects that are entirely at the decision of the manager itself, no way around reading the api doc of the concrete manager.

API doc for GridLayout:

```
 * In addition, the horizontal and vertical gaps are set to the 
 * specified values. Horizontal gaps are placed between each
 * of the columns. Vertical gaps are placed between each of
 * the rows.
```

API doc for FlowLayout:

```
 * @param      hgap    the horizontal gap between components
 *                     and between the components and the 
 *                     borders of the <code>Container</code>
 * @param      vgap    the vertical gap between components
 *                     and between the components and the 
 *                     borders of the <code>Container</code>
```

From your code, I guess you expected to achieve the GridLayout to have the same gap-behaviour as the FlowLayout :-)

As the LayoutManager of the levelPanel's parent (parent == mainP) is FlowLayout, you can - as an alternative to setting the a Border to mainP - set the gap of the FlowLayout:

```
 mainP.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 50));
```

Comment: +1 that is right I forgot about that. Much nicer to do that for the layout itself. Though hard to say which solution is 'best' since, as all in life, it depends what you are exactly after. If you are after a gap at the top only then set the border for parent else as explained by @kleopatra.